# Is the Gigabyte B365 HD3 motherboard compatible with PCI Express x16 3.0?

Tags: compatibility

Is this Gigabyte B365 HD3 ATX motherboard compatible with PCI Express x16 3.0? 
I tried to see on other sites but could not find anything.

Answer (score 2):

[Gigabyte's own website](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/B365-HD3-rev-10/sp#sp) is the go-to place to answer this.  The Expansion Slots section show **YES**.

> 1 x PCI Express x16 slot, running at x16 (PCIEX16)  * For optimum performance, if only one PCI Express graphics card is to be installed, be sure to install it in the PCIEX16 slot.
>
> 1 x PCI Express x16 slot, running at x4 (PCIEX4)
>
> 4 x PCI Express x1 slots  (All of the PCI Express slots conform to PCI Express 3.0 standard.)
>
> 1 x M.2 Socket 1 connector for the wireless communication module (M2_WIFI)